# Searching a 2-Dimensional Tuple/List in Python

Tags: python

I want to search a `tuple of tuples` for a particular string and return the index of the parent tuple. I seem to run into variations of this kind of search frequently.

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

I.E:

```
derp = (('Cat','Pet'),('Dog','Pet'),('Spock','Vulcan'))
i = None
for index, item in enumerate(derp):
    if item[0] == 'Spock':
         i = index
         break
>>>print i
2
```

I could generalize this into a small utility function that takes an iterable, an index (I've hard coded `0` in the example) and a search value. It does the trick but I've got this notion that there's probably a one-liner for it ;)

I.E:

```
def pluck(iterable, key, value):
    for index, item in enumerate(iterable):
        if item[key] == value:
             return index
    return None
```

Comment: Why do you want the index and not the value?

Comment: Just a particular context. Another function I have takes a tuple and and index, then says "the tuple at index i is the one the one currently active."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It does the trick but I've got this notion that there's probably a one-liner for it ;)

The one-liner is probably *not* the pythonic way to do it :)

The method you have used looks fine.

*Edit*:

If you want to be cute:

```
return next( (i for i,(k,v) in enumerate(items) if k=='Spock'),None)
```

`next` takes a generator expression and returns the next value or the second argument (in this case `None`) once the generator has been exhausted.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do:

```
dict(derp)[<key_name>]
```

eg.

```
dict(derp)['Cat']
```

which will give you 'Pet'

Comment: This seems much more elegant than the accepted answer - is there a downside?

Comment: @AaronPollock, the marked answer was posted on Feb 2010, and this one on Nov 2012, perhaps that's why :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're often searching the same tuple, you can build a dict.

```
lookup_table = dict((key, i) for i, (key, unused) in enumerate(derp))

print lookup_table['Spock']
--> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting it in one line would be:

```
[d[0] for d in derp].index("Spock")
```

I'm not sure if the iterator evaluates all values before calling index, and therefor being inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Lambdas are fun!

```
return reduce(
    lambda x,(i,(a,b)): i,
    filter(
        lambda (i,(a,b)): a == "Spock",
        enumerate(depr)
    ),
    None
)
```

Comment: The problems with `filter()` are: (1) it will always search the whole list and (2) it will return a list of matches, rather then any match's index.

Comment: (1) true (2) can be worked around with map or reduce (see edited post)

Comment: By the way, the original code posted is fine and doesn't have this "flaw". Loving lambdas is a personal trait ;)

Comment: maybe i'm missing something: what's wrong with the pluck function defined by Koobz? IMHO is more readable, more generic and with better performances: `100000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 usec per loop` for the function defined by Koobz and `100000 loops, best of 3: 5.82 usec per loop` for the yours.

Comment: The functional way to write this is `itertools.dropwhile(lambda a: a[0] != 'Spock', derp).next()`

Comment: LOL maybe there's a lesson to be learned here. Darn Python keeps me second guessing myself ;)

Ron's example did lead me in some interesting directions. Haven't played with filter yet.

What happened to the whole 'one obvious way to do it' thing ;)

Comment: The pluck function defined by Koobz is perfectly fine. Its clean, legible and pythonic.

Comment: @Paul I would not say unpythonic once all elements are well in python. Unreadable is subjective, I can read it fine for example. But for the itertools thing, thanks, that is a very useful part.