# Searching within nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have this variable:

```
myList = [
    range(27,35), 
    range(19,27), 
    range(11,19), 
    range(92,100), 
    range(125,133) 
]
```

I would like to search the list for an item (lets say 98) and return the index of the list containing that item (in this case 3).

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206174/788054. It seems great, however I'm having trouble adapting it to lists, and generators confuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generator expression like this and get the next value with the `next` function

```
next(idx for idx, item in enumerate(myList) if 98 in item)
# 3
```

This can be understood like this

```
for idx, item in enumerate(myList):
    if 98 in item:
        print idx
```

The difference between generator/generator expression and normal functions/code are as follows

1. They will not be evaluated till we invoke them (lazy evaluation). For example, consider this list comprehension

   ```
   a = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(myList) if 98 in item]
   print a
   [3]
   ```

   this executes immediately and gives the results. But, the gen exps are not like this

   ```
   a = (idx for idx, item in enumerate(myList) if 98 in item)
   print(a)
   # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f599213b3a8>
   ```

   it returns a generator object. We have to manually invoke it with `next` protocol.
2. They don't exhaust with the execution immediately. For example, lets say there are more than one matches

   ```
   print([idx for idx, item in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4]) if item % 2])
   # [0, 2]
   ```

   LC immediately returns both the indexes. But, when we use GenExp with `next` prototcol, it yields the first index, retains the current execution context and transfers the control to the invoker. When we call `next`on it again, it resumes the execution from where it left of.

   ```
   gen_exp = ((idx for idx, item in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4]) if item % 2))
   print(next(gen_exp))
   # 0
   print(next(gen_exp))
   # 2
   print(next(gen_exp))
   # StopIteration
   ```

   **Note:** When the generators are exhausted they raise `StopIteration`.

   This is really helpful, when you need to iterate over a huge list of items, or processing a huge file, you don't have to store the entire list/file in memory. You can simply iterate over the contents, process them and move on to the next chunk.

**Note:**

1. Once the generators are exhausted they cannot be used again. You need to create a new generator.
2. You cannot skip or move backwards in a generator. Its a single step, forward only iterator.
3. Generators are best suitable for iteration. But if you want to convert the list of values from a generator to a list, you can simply use `list` function. For example,

   ```
   print([idx for idx, item in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4]) if item % 2])
   # [0, 2]
   gen_exp = ((idx for idx, item in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4]) if item % 2))
   print(list(gen_exp))
   # [0, 2]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
[index for index, l in enumerate(myList) if 98 in l]
```